# Graphviz user interface in windows

Tags: windows, user-interface, graph, graphviz

Hello maybe someone knows if graphviz has user interface for windows? because i have found one for mac os x, but that one was not working for me.

Also i have tried contacting graphviz team, but they hadn`t respond me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one myself it`s GVEdit.